# Save String from Servlet

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, servlets

I have an HTTPServlet and it sends Data to my Database. I also want to display that Data(its a String) in an `<table>`.

For that I tried to use AJAX.

```
var responseText = '';
$.ajax({ type: "POST",   
         url: "/InsertServlet",   
         success : function(text)
         {
             responseText = text;
         }
});

alert(responseText);
```

Unfortunately the String is empty.
Anyone got an idea?
Mfg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample code creates the empty string responseText, then sets up your ajax call with the jQuery ajax method (but it isn't called yet), and lastly it reports the responseText, which at this point is still an empty string. The responseText variable isn't populated until after the ajax call and the "success" function fires.

Move the alert() to within your ajax "success" function.

```
var responseText = '';
$.ajax({ type: "POST",
         url: "/InsertServlet",   
         success : function(text)
         {
             responseText = text;
             alert(responseText);
         } });
```

Comment: this works for me thx, unluckily i call response.sendRedirect(...) in my Servlet and i get the plain html code as new String O.o.Still thank you :)